# Array can be sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem with sorting array of char. There is a array 2 * 5 3 4 that should be sorted from file, but I can finde the error in the code. Compiler just read the array. Any suggestion, comment

```
#include <iostream> // cin cout endl
#include <fstream> // ifstream
#include <sstream> // stringstream
#include <stdlib.h> //exit
#include <vector>
#include "insertionSort.h";

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::vector;
using namespace std;


const int MAX_CHARS = 200; // max length of each line to read from the input file

template<class T>
void readSortOutput( char* typeName, vector<T> v, ifstream &inStream );

int main( )
{
    int array_size= 1024;
    char *array = new char[array_size];
    int possition;
    ifstream inStream("/home/xx/Downloads/input.txt");
    cout << "Insertion sort algorithm driver program" << endl;

    if( inStream.fail( ) )
    {
        cerr << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
   while (!inStream.eof()&&possition<array_size)
   {
       inStream.get(array[possition]);
       possition++;
   }
   array[possition-1] = '\0';
   cout <<"Display the array" <<endl <<endl;
   for (int i=0;array[i] !='\0';i++)
   {
       cout <<array[i];
   }

    vector<int> intVector;
    readSortOutput( (char*)"int", intVector, inStream );

    vector<double> dblVector;
    readSortOutput( (char*)"double", dblVector, inStream );

    vector<char> chrVector;
    readSortOutput( (char*)"char", chrVector, inStream );

    inStream.close( );

    return 0;
}

template<class T>
void readSortOutput( char* typeName, vector<T> v, ifstream &inStream )
{
    // read a line from the input stream into a stringstream
    char fileLine[MAX_CHARS];
    std::stringstream ss;
    inStream.getline(fileLine, MAX_CHARS);
    ss << fileLine;

    // extract elements of the specified type from the stringstream
    T elem;
       while (ss >> elem) {
        v.push_back( elem );
    }

    cout << endl << typeName << " vector before insertion sort: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size( ); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    insertionSort( v ); // the sort itself

    cout << typeName << " vector after insertion sort: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size( ); i++)
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return;
} // readSortOutput
```

insertionSort.h

```
#ifndef INSERTIONSORT_H
#define INSERTIONSORT_H

#include <vector> // vector
#include <iostream> // cin cout endl
#include <fstream> // ifstream
#include <sstream> // stringstream
#include <stdlib.h> //exit

using std::vector;

/*template<class T>
void insertionSort(vector<T>& data); // function replaces the given argument
*/


template<class T>
void insertionSort(vector<T>& data)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size( ); i++)
        for (size_t j = i; j < data.size( ); j++)
            if (data[ j ] < data[ i ])
            { // swap values
                T temp = data[ j ];
                data[ j ] = data[ i ];
                data[ i ] = temp;
            }

    return;
}
#endif  // INSERTIONSORT_H
```

Comment: What _exact_ problem are you experiencing? 'Compiler just read the array' doesn't make much sense, to tell the truth since it's the compiler's job to read the code. What's more, you can just write `using namespace std;` and `cout` and `cerr`, etc will be available without using `std::`.

Comment: Just get this message: 2 * 5 3 4

Comment: to be honest, I don't understand what your comment means: what does '2 * 5 3 4' mean??

Comment: It mean that I get this in console. It should be like:

2 3 4 5 *

Comment: What's contained in the `/home/demir/Downloads/input.txt` file?

Comment: It contatin those number that should be sorted. 2 * 5 3 4

Comment: Whats up with the *, have you heared of `std::swap` and how is something with `swap supposed to be an insertion sort? (Reads like a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) for me).

Comment: Did you _get_ `Insertion sort algorithm driver program` _in console_, preceding `2 * 5 3 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (!inStream.eof()&&possition<array_size)
   {
       inStream.get(array[possition]);
       possition++;
   }
```

When you run through the loop above, you are consuming all the input. Therefore, when you call `readSortOutput` there is nothing left to read. You should use `inStream.seekg(0);` to reset your position in the file before trying to read the array again.

Comment: There is problem with reading, i debug program. Debuger stop here:

    char fileLine[MAX_CHARS];
    std::stringstream ss;
    inStream.getline(fileLine, MAX_CHARS);
    ss << fileLine;
    T elem;
       while (ss >> elem) {
        v.push_back( elem );
    }

Comment: You will probably need to `ss.seekg(0);` after writing to `ss` as well, so that the stream reads from the beginning.